# Godot parallax background is not covering the entire screen

Tags: godot, parallax-scrolling

I have started learning to use godot and I've created simple 2D scene with a spaceship that you can control. I want to add some background so that you can see if you're flying or stopped.

I made an image 846x846 pixels and created a ParallaxBackground and a ParallaxLayer in it. This is how I set up the layer:

[image: image.png]

I did not change anything else.

However, when I run the game the background fails to catch up, when I fly in one direction, I will reach uncovered area, then it will get covered few moments later:

[image: image.png]

This is what it looks like in the editor:

[image: image.png]

It seems that the parallax background repeats the contents 4 times only. That makes pretty much impossible to cover the entire screen in all instances, so I bet that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my project, the solution to this issue was to uncheck the `Centered` property in the Offset group of each sprite child of a `ParallaxLayer` node:

[image: uncheck centered property of Sprite2D]

If you've set the `Mirroring` property of the ParallaxLayer to the correct dimensions (including accounting for any scaling on the Sprite2D nodes), this should align the textures correctly in the parallax background.

Comment: Worked for me, although I am not exactly sure why. I tried offsetting the parallax manually before, which seems a lot similar what this does, but it didn't work. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: Hm, too bad you have to do this on every sprite. I added an offset parent at the very top with position offset = half-repeat size. I wish Godot would just auto-offset textures so it always work, but I understand why limiting the engine to two repetitions is optimal. This should be better explained in the doc/API doc though.

Answer (score 2):

Incase someone's facing the same problem,

A solution is to enable repeat on your image in the import tab:
[image]

Then increase the sprite `region_rect` by *2 (or multiply by whatever suites you):
[image]

and do the same in `ParallaxLayer` `mirroring` option

[image]

This *should* work, instead of manually increasing the texture resolution like an idiot <strike>which I definitely did not do for hours</strike>

Comment: While not incorrect, this fixes the issue by simply covering a wider area. So you still draw a rectangle the size of a full screen outside of camera view, but the area is so big that it covers the camera view anyway. See Problematic's answer for a way to fix offset without extra drawing (maybe camera clipping avoids extra cost anyway, I'm not sure how it works with repeated textures).